# "Which one" or "Which ones"

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

What should I use? When you ask a person to choose only one kind of thing.

> 1. **Which one** do you like? apples, candies or cookies?

or

> 2. **Which ones** do you like? apples, candies or cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Which one.

"Which ones" invites multiple answers.

Comment: Better, I think, is just 'which' (which do you like?).

Answer (score 0):

'Which ones do you like?' is a general question - we can easily like two or all three of those choices, so inviting 'multiple answers' is not a bad thing. But if I'm offering you *one* of these things as a snack *now*, I might ask 'Which one do you like?', but would probably ask 'Which one would you like?'.